# Copy value between two input type="datetime-local" fields using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML5 form with two input type="datetime-local" fields. Once the date time is selected for the first field, the second needs to have the same value as suggestion but can be overridden manually. Can I achieve it by using Javascript? I'm not using any lib or framework.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('.start_datetime');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('.end_datetime');
  result.textContent = `${event.target.value}`;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="start_datetime" id="start_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="start_datetime" name="start_datetime" placeholder="" title="Start Datetime" required value="">

  <label for="end_datetime" id="end_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="end_datetime" name="end_datetime" placeholder="" title="End Datetime" required value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Wrong selector `document.querySelector('.start_datetime');` should be `document.getElementById('start_datetime');`

Comment: or `.querySelector("#start_datetime")` (the same for `#end_datetime`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things

- `document.querySelector('.start_datetime');` should be `document.getElementById('start_datetime');` or `document.querySelector("#start_datetime")`
- `const result = document.querySelector('.end_datetime');` needed to be `const result = document.getElementById('end_datetime');`
- set value, not textContent
- no need for the backticks
- using function instead of fat arrow you can use `this`

```js
const startElement = document.getElementById('start_datetime');
const endElement = document.getElementById('end_datetime');

startElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  endElement.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="start_datetime" id="start_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="start_datetime" name="start_datetime" placeholder="" title="Start Datetime" required value="">

  <label for="end_datetime" id="end_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="end_datetime" name="end_datetime" placeholder="" title="End Datetime" required value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you using wrong selector  `class` instead of `id`

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#start_datetime');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  const result = document.querySelector('#end_datetime');
   result.value = event.target.value;
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You nearly had the right solution, but with `querySelector` you hat to use a `#` if you are searching for an id or you use `getElementById` with the id without a prefix.
Secondly for setting the value just use `.value`, `textContent`is for e.g. a DIV the right choice.

```js
const selectElement = document.getElementById('start_datetime');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const result = document.getElementById('end_datetime');
    result.value = selectElement.value;
});
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="start_datetime" id="start_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start_datetime" name="start_datetime" placeholder="" title="Start Datetime" required  value="">

    <label for="end_datetime" id="end_datetime_label">Datetime</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end_datetime" name="end_datetime" placeholder="" title="End Datetime" required  value="">
</form>
```